# Form Validator In Perl Catalyst

Tags: forms, perl, validation, catalyst

I want to compare two date fields in form with Catalyst MVC Framework.

I use FormValidator::Simple::Auto by create my owner plugin

Valid.pm

with function

sub COMPARE_DATE {
    my ($self, $params, $args) = @_;

```
my $start_date = $params->[0];
my $end_date = $params->[1];
unless (defined $start_date and defined $end_date) {
    FormValidator::Simple::Exception->throw(
    qq/validation "COMPARE_DATE" needs two keys of data./
    );
}
return $start_date lt $end_date ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

}

But I don't know how to use in profiles.yml

I have just try
start_date:
  -rule: COMPARE_DATE
  with: [start_date, end_date]
  message: Start date must be greater than end date

But not success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.12/lib/DateTime.pm) ?

It seems to me that `$star_date lt $end_date` does not do what you are hoping for,
it is a string compare, not date compare.

```
use DateTime;
my $start_date = DateTime->new({ year => $year, month => $month, day => $day });
my $end_date = DateTime->new({ year => $year, month => $month, day => $day });

my $diff = $start_date - $end_date; # returns DateTime::Duration, this should be useful
```

You will have to read the docs for the right parser to use given the input you have,
it is not per se necessary to get day, month, year from the string yourself.

The doc is pretty good and the module very reliable, it thinks of things most of us would not ;).

Comment: It's still OK, but I want to call it from profiles.yml, how to do it? Thanks